# Is it possible to add structural directives like *ngIf and *ngFor to elements that are added to DOM using renderer 2?

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

this.renderer.setAttribute(this.element.nativeElement, '*ngIf', 'test');

Can we use like this?

Comment: did you **try** adding?

Comment: yes, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, But I think that has no sense, using this.renderer 2 you can add somay HTML elements you want. Anyway, **sure** there're a better aproach than use renderer